# how to set current location getting from goelocation into google map using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm trying to set the current user location i got from the geolocation into google map but I'm facing issue, the map is not showing at all.

```js
const Map = () => {
    const [lats, setLats] = useState('');
    const [lngs, setLngs] = useState('');
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

    const getLocation = () => {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
          setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
        } else {
          setStatus('Locating...');
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            setStatus(null);
            setLats(position.coords.latitude);
            setLngs(position.coords.longitude);
          }, () => {
            setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
          });
        }
      }


    const defaultProps = {
        center: {
          lat: lats, //this is where my problem lies
          lng: lngs // but if I set static value to lat and lng for example lat:3.66666 and lng: 8.6666, the map displays fine
       
        },
        zoom: 11
      };
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
             <Button onClick={getLocation} variant="primary">Find me</Button>
             <p>{status}</p>
                {lats && <p>Latitude: {lats}</p>}
                {lngs && <p>Longitude: {lngs}</p>}
            <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
            defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
            defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
            >
            <LocationMarker
                lat={59.955413}
                lng={30.337844}
                text="My Marker"
            />
            </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What error do you get from this? Can you post that into your question please?

Comment: Thanks, it not showing any error by the map is not rendering

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the string as the initial value in your state, instead of numbers which is required by the `GoogleMapReact` component.
Lets update these lines:

```
const [lats, setLats] = useState('');
const [lngs, setLngs] = useState('');
```

to

```
const [lats, setLats] = useState(0);
const [lngs, setLngs] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Thanks man, it rendered and nothing is showing  but I tried to console.log (lats) and (lngs), at first they return 0 and later the returns the actual value